# multidimentional array printing in a php class

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, fpdf

There is a FPDF class and I am passing an array in the class with a function which name is **productList**.

```
$myclass->productList($table_rows);
```

The array has some rows from a MySql table

like

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [id] => 170 [product] => 10211 [qty] => 1 [price] => 50 )
[1] => Array ( [id] => 171 [product] => 10211 [qty] => 1 [price] => 50 ) 1
```

I am using an extra function to resolve the array but it show only first row.
Additionally It show table column name with data

eg id1,data1##somedata

My desired ouput is

1,#somedata,#some
2,#somedata,#some

Desired Output image:

[image: Desired Output image]

Current Output image:

[image: Current Output image]

First I am posting array print function

```
function makeNestedList(array $Array){
$w = array(90, 25, 20, 25,30);
foreach($Array as $Key => $Value){
    $Output = $Key;
    if(is_array($Value)){
        $Output .= $this->makeNestedList($Value);
    }else{
        $Output .= $Value;

    }
   //Product List
    $this->Cell($w[0],6,$Output,'LR',0,'L',1);
}

return $Output;
}
```

And the product list function which is responsible to print

```
function productList($pdata)
{
//Function to print product table 

// Product Table Header
$header = array('Product', 'Qty', 'Rate', 'Discount','Subtotal'); 
//cell width $w
$w = array(90, 25, 20, 25,30);
for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
$this->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,0,'C',true);
$this->Ln();

// Product Data  <===== Here is problem

$this->makeNestedList($pdata);

// Closing line and extra
$this->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');
$this->Ln();
}
```

Comment: May I ask. are you merging same products into one total?

Comment: Can you explain the comment,thanks

Comment: example on your array you have 2 product name of 10211. I assume they are the same. and where is the discount amount?

Comment: Actually I wrote this array to illustrate array time. this is not related to codes...

Comment: So ok I will assume that the array contains the value on your desired output. Please wait.

Answer (score 0):

After tries of long hard methods I got this simple solution

```
//get $pdata
$this->productList($tablerows);


function productList($pdata)
{
and set a loop
foreach($table_rows as $key => $value)
{
$this->Cell($w[0],6,$value['product'],'LR',0,'L',$fill);
$this->Cell($w[1],6,$value['qty'],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
$this->Cell($w[2],6,$value['price'],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
$this->Cell($w[3],6,$value['discount'],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
$this->Cell($w[4],6,$value['subtotal'],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
$this->Ln();
$fill = !$fill;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if ever you array data looks like this:

```
array (
            array ( 'product' => 10211, 'qty' => 1, 'rate' => 50, 'discount' => 50 , 'subtotal' => 50 ),
            array ( 'product' => 10212, 'qty' => 1, 'rate' => 100, 'discount' => 100 , 'subtotal' => 100 )
        );
```

This code may work for you. I saw that you concatenate all the value of the array into the `$Output` and put into one cell. You shouldn't do that if you wanted to produce the table.

```
function makeNestedList(array $Array){
$w = array(90, 25, 20, 25,30);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($Array) ; $i++) { 
    $ii = 0;
        foreach ($Array[$i] as $key => $value) {
            $this->Cell($w[$ii],6,$Output,'LR',0,'L',1);
            $ii++;
        }
    }
}
```